# Parameters not reflect Panel in stimulsoft (C#)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, stimulsoft

showing parameters panel the report.
I do not want show.

[image]
<sub>(source: [picofile.com](http://s3.picofile.com/file/8188412526/showParameter.png))</sub>

**My Code is:**

```
StiReport sr = new StiReport();
sr.Load(ClsVariable.Address + "ReportCustomerBuy.mrt");
sr.Dictionary.Variables["Ccode"].Value = txtCode.Text;
sr.Dictionary.Variables["Cname"].Value = txtName.Text;
sr.Dictionary.Variables["Ctel"].Value = txtTel.Text;
sr.Dictionary.Variables["Caddress"].Value = txtAddress.Text;
sr.Dictionary.Variables["Cfathername"].Value = txtFatherName.Text;
sr.Dictionary.Variables["Cdate"].Value = txtDate.Text;
sr.Dictionary.Variables["CPay"].Value = lblGivePrice.Text;
sr.Dictionary.Variables["CHesabK"].Value = lblPriceKK.Text;
sr.Dictionary.Variables["CBedehkar"].Value = s;
sr.Show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the [request from user property](http://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=4953)

```
sr.Dictionary.Variables["Ccode"].RequestFromUser = false;
```